# How do I insert or load images to the drawable folder in the resources folder, using android studio 4?

Tags: android

I am using a windows 10 machine and am dragging images from a folder to the drawable folder in the resources folder using android studio 4, but the error message says:  "‘C’ is not a valid file-based resource name character:  File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9 or underscore."

Comment: Try moving the image manually via explorer and remember what Android Studio told: lowercase a-z, 0-9 and underscores. Any other name will not be accepted while compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Capitals are not allowed for naming conventions. As the message says:

> ...*resource names must contain only **lowercase a-z**, **0-9** or **underscore***

So just change the name.

Comment: The file directory is as follows:  C:Documents\Cartoon Cat Pics\Cat1.jpg  This means that I will never be able to load pictures from my laptop or computer.  How else can I load pictures when I do coding, using Android Studio 4?

Comment: The challenge that I have with this is the C drive.  I will never be able to change the C:\ to c:\ because this is the file path where everything is stored on computers and laptops.

Comment: Wait, dont you just want to copy the Cat.jpg, to the drawable folder?